# Tree View Parent-Child Full Hierarchy

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have created the below treeview for a folder navigation system:

Looks Like:

[image: Tree View]

My Code:

```
string[] RootFolders = Directory.GetDirectories(txtRootDirectory.Text.Trim());

        foreach (string dir0 in RootFolders)
        {
            if (dir0.Contains("_In"))
            {
                TreeViewItem path = new TreeViewItem() { Header = new DirectoryInfo(dir0).Name };

                string[] MainFolder = Directory.GetDirectories(dir0);
                foreach(string dir1 in MainFolder)
                {
                    TreeViewItem path1 = new TreeViewItem() { Header = new DirectoryInfo(dir1).Name };
                    path.Items.Add(path1);

                    string[] SubFolder = Directory.GetDirectories(dir1);
                    foreach (string dir2 in SubFolder)
                    {
                        TreeViewItem path2 = new TreeViewItem() { Header = new DirectoryInfo(dir2).Name };
                        path1.Items.Add(path2);
                    }
                }



                tree.Items.Add(path);
            }
        }
```

What I need is to be able to get is the name of all parent folders for the final child node in the sequence and concatenate them together to make a directory. For instance, if the 'ascx Staging Application' tree item is selected, I need to return 'ascx Staging Application','Web Applications', '_In Development' so I can create a string which will be used to open this file. (i.e. "c:_In Development\Web Applications\ascx Staging Application.sln")

All I can come up with so far is this, from here everything seems to fall apart...

```
private void tree_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        TreeViewItem trvItem = (TreeViewItem)tree.SelectedItem;

        if (trvItem != null)
        {
            TreeViewItem trvParent = (TreeViewItem)trvItem.Parent;
            MessageBox.Show(trvParent.Header.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A quite simple solution is to assign the path to the `Tag` property of each TreeViewElement.

The code to read the selected path looks like this:

```
private void tree_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        TreeViewItem trvItem = (TreeViewItem)tree.SelectedItem;

        if (trvItem != null)
        {
            String path = (String)trvItem.Tag;
            MessageBox.Show(path);
        }
    }
```

Comment: A better and more simple way is using DataBindings. If you need an example, I can post one tomorrow.